# Dictionary doesn't throw exception for nonexistent key

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I have

```
CurrentAppSimulator.LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses["nonexistentEntry"]
```

([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store.licenseinformation#Windows_ApplicationModel_Store_LicenseInformation_ProductLicenses))

and it doesn't throw an exception.

Is that expected? Will it always do that?

Comment: That can't be your whole statement, it wouldn't get past the compiler. `Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`

Comment: @RufusL Correct. It is `var l = ... ;`. I was just showing the probably pertinent part.

Comment: Post the entire statement, please.

Comment: And what is the exact type of ProductLicenses

Comment: `ProductLicenses` is an `IMapView`, not a `Dictionary`.

Comment: LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses is not a Dictionary. it is IReadOnlyDictionary. And implimintation could be not a Dictionary.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange I see you're right according to the docs. VS, however, shows it as an IReadOnlyDictionary (which is actually mentioned in the docs).

Comment: @IvanChepikov Your comment seems logical. You can transform it into an answer. And if you have more information as to whether I can rely on it not throwing an exception, that would be welcome as well.

Answer (score 2):

As posted above by a commentator, it seems that though the variable is an `IReadOnlyDictionary` - that does *not* prove it's a `Dictionary`. It might be implemented otherwise.

Comment: Just to add a little bit more depth to this. Interfaces only guarantee the *shape*, not the *behavior*.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in comments:

LicenseInformation.ProductLicenses is not a Dictionary. According to documentataion it is IReadOnlyDictionary.

I didn't find information about its behaviour or implementation, but if check it in runtime you can find out that it is System.__ComObject:System.MarshalByRefObject. It mean that it is definitely not a Dictionary.

It is better to check an existence of a key before accessing it, because there is no certainty that behaviour will not change in future.

Comment: This is the best scenario. Always check to see if the key exists before attempting to access it, especially with future proofing for changes as described in the answer.